# Why cannot kill process fastboot_cmd.exe using taskkill /F in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process

I want to kill process fastboot_cmd.exe in my desktop PC, `tasklist` output:

```
    Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
    ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
    System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K
    System                           4 Services                   0        368 K
    svchost.exe                    708 Services                   0      7,764 K
...
    audiodg.exe                   8260 Services                   0     18,368 K
    fastboot_cmd.exe              8240 Console                    1      4,140 K
    tasklist.exe                  1864 Console                    1      6,012 K
```

Then I ran `taskkill`

```
E:\>taskkill /F /T /IM fastboot_cmd.exe
SUCCESS: The process with PID 8240 (child process of PID 6228) has been terminat
ed.
```

but in fact this process still in `tasklist`,

```
    Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
    ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
    System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K
    System                           4 Services                   0        368 K
    smss.exe                       272 Services                   0        464 K
   ...
    chrome.exe                    4772 Console                    1     67,496 K
    fastboot_cmd.exe              1964 Console                    1      4,132 K
    tasklist.exe                  6636 Console                    1      6,028 K
```

How to kill it persistently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your command output for `E:\>taskkill /F /T /IM fastboot_cmd.exe` - `The process with PID 8240` so the command only killed `PID 8240` but your looking at `PID 1964` which is a brand new instance so it most likely started a new task.

Troubleshooting to perform

> tasklist | findstr fastboot_cmd.exe

This will output all instances of `fastboot_cmd.exe` in `tasklist` and display their PID

Example from my PC:

```
C:\Users\Foo>tasklist | findstr cmd
cmd.exe                       9556 Console                    1        680 K
cmd.exe                      10916 Console                    1      1,352 K
cmd.exe                       1024 Console                    1      1,096 K
cmd.exe                       4840 Console                    1      6,064 K
```

From here you can see I have multiple instances so I would then run `taskkill /f /t /pid 9556 /pid 10916 /pid 1024 /pid 4840`

OR:

> FOR /F "tokens=2" %G IN ('tasklist ^| findstr cmd') DO taskkill /f /t /pid %G

This would do it in 1 line just a mouthful to remember

Now run another `tasklist | findstr fastboot_cmd.exe` and check the PID value if it's changed then something on your system is starting this task again once it's been closed